# Ruby loop inside JS in order to make a chart?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm new with charts.

I need to place dynamic info using chart.js , in the data:

```
data: ['1','2','3','4']
```

I need to get that data from each client, and separate it by a comma:

```
Clients.each do |client| 
   client.contacts.count
end
```

How can I loop through the Client class inside my javascript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's the correct way recommended by the rails community for doing that but you can do it by changing your file name to erb format. For example if your js file is named `clients.js`, change it to `clients.js.erb`. Then you can simply use rails functions like you would in an html.erb file.

Example:

```
<%= Client.all.each do |client| %>
  <%= client.contacts.count %>
<%= end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would convert your data to JSON in Ruby, maybe like this:

```
<script>
  var chart = new Chart(<%= JSON.dump(Clients.contact_counts) %>);
</script>
```

You will need to convert the data to JSON at some point, so best to do it explicitly right there when you initialize your Chart.